# xml or sqlite file?

Tags: android, sqlite

i need hints for SQLite; I receive in SOAP or REST format a large XML (betwen 200 and 5000 entries depending on the user, with around 30 columns) that i parse to a local SQLite db.
This operation takes too much time for the users (from 10 seconds up to 2 minutes), so i wanted to know :

Is it possible under a window server (Delphi XE2 home made server) to create the SQLite database file and send the whole file to the mobile; Then on mobile side, replace the database file with the new one (data are not modified on client side, i can replace file with no regrets ^^ ) ?

On a rooted mobile, i just can't find the SQLite database file (searched for it with esFileExplorer, /data, /dbdata, /sdcard/data... nowhere) so i just don't know where i will have to put that file in the end...

Comment: Try searching in /data/data/"Your App name"/databases

Comment: Given that you can change the returned data of the web service, why not use JSON?  Much faster than XML.  Are you also doing a bulk update to SQLite or row by row?

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah , i went through everything under /data to be sure...

Comment: @Simon , I do use JSON with REST, but as you point it out I update it row by row. actually i just have it in a memory object, i'm trying to find the best way to save it in SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

You can download the database having latest data & replace it with current database. Find an example here of "[How to use existing data base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728)", link for sample project is also [there](http://sdrv.ms/N857Wn).

**EDIT**:

You need to modify it according to your needs.

You can delete your existing database by using `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);`

Comment: thanks for the information, i'll try it as soon as possible ^^